# Union of two languages

Tags: formal-languages

If I have these languages:

$$\begin{align*}
S&=\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h\}\\
A&=\{b,g\}\\
B&=\{a,b,c,d,f,h\}\\
C&=\{a,c,g\}\,,
\end{align*}$$

Writing $X'$ for the complement of a set $X$, what would B'∪ C consist of? Would the elements of this language then be C = {c g}?

Also if I have B ∩ (A ∪ C'), would the elements of this language then be {ab bb cb db fb hb}? Since A ∪ C' would = {b} then combined with B we have {ab bb cb db fb hb}

Comment: Hi Ducksauce88! If my answer helped, click the check mark to accept! (If it didn't, let me know if I can clarify or expand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The union symbol $\cup$ means "everything in the first set along with everything in the second set" (ignoring duplicates).

$$
\begin{aligned}
B' &= S - B &= \{e, g\}\\
B' \cup C &= \{e, g\} \cup C &= \{a, c, e, g\}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Likewise, $A \cup C'$ is (everything in $A$) together with (everything not in $C$).

$$
A \cup C' = A \cup \{b, d, e, f, h\} = \{b, d, e, f, g, h\}\\
$$

The intersection symbol $\cap$ means "only the items in both sets." It doesn't involve the creation of new elements (as in your "bb" and "cb") -- you might be thinking of Cartesian product $\times$.

So $B \cap (A \cup C')$ would be $\{b, d, f, h\}$.

Here's a Venn diagram explaining union and intersection:
[image]